# Spinner populated in xml shows as empty (Android)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-spinner

I have three spinners, two populated from code and the third is from XML arrays.xml. This third one is not showing any labels, just the empty lines for every item.

The error I get in Logcat:

W/ResourceType(22121): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c8 (t=7 e=712) in package 0 (error -75)

But I don't know what to do with this line... I did xml filled spinners earlier and they were ok, I don't know what i'm doing wrong...

My layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_from" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_from"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_length"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_length"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_start" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_length"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/length_value"
        android:entryValues="@array/length_value"
        android:defaultValue="10"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_length"  />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_from_lesson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/check_from_lesson"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_length" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_lesson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/check_from_lesson" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_select_from_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_select"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_lesson" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_ok"
        android:layout_below="@id/spinner_lesson"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/button_select_from_list"
        android:onClick="onOkButtonPress" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

My arrays.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="length_value">
        <item>5</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>15</item>
        <item>20</item>
        <item>25</item>
   </array>
</resources>
```

My code which calls the layout and populates the other 2 spinners:

```
public void setTestParams() {

        setContentView(R.layout.main_popup_layout);
        sp_lesson = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_lesson);     
        Spinner sp_start = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_start);
        sp_lesson.setEnabled(false);

        List<String> lessons = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> start = new ArrayList<String>();
        lessons=getLessons();
        start=getStart();

        ArrayAdapter<String> spAdapterStart = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, start);
        ArrayAdapter<String> spAdapterLessons = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lessons);

        spAdapterStart.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spAdapterLessons.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp_start.setAdapter(spAdapterStart);
        sp_lesson.setAdapter(spAdapterLessons);


        spAdapterLessons.notifyDataSetChanged();
        spAdapterStart.notifyDataSetChanged();

        final CheckBox cb_lesson = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_from_lesson);
        cb_lesson.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(cb_lesson.isChecked()){
                    sp_lesson.setEnabled(true);
                }else{
                    sp_lesson.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<string-array name="length_value">
        <item>5</item>
        <item>10</item>
        <item>15</item>
        <item>20</item>
        <item>25</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: It looks good, the labels are visible now, but I still got the warn message in logcat every time I click on the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

The Spinner in which you are getting your data from resource but can't found it

then you should add :

```
 android:entries="@array/length_value"
```

to that **Spinner** in your xml file...

and also change it with:

```
<string-array name="length_value">
    <item>5</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>25</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: The spinner has this line already. I replaced the array to string-array in arrays.xml, and it shows correctly, but i still have the error message.